# How do I make Text Editor display an apostrophe instead of a single quote?

Tags: php, macos, text-editor

I can't parse properly using Text Editor because it interprets the apostrophe key on my keyboard as a single quote  (‘ - slanted).  PHP requires an apostrophe (' - straight).  When I press this key anywhere else (browser, etc. it displays as an apostrophe.

Works - `<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>`

Doesn't work - `<?php echo ‘<p>Hello World</p>’; ?>`

How can I get Text Editor to display the straight apostrophe instead of a single quote?

Comment: `‘<p>Hello World</p>’` doesn't work because they're smart/curly quotes which will throw a 500 error. Plus, your keyboard may be configured to another language other than English standard keyboard.

Comment: don't use a text editor. use a CODE editor.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have TextEdit in rich text mode. This will only cause you horrible pain trying to write code.

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, or the menu item `Format -> Make Plain Text` if you're editing code.

There are better choices for code editors on OSX though, like [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/), which is free.

Answer (score 0):

You won't change PHP syntax unless you wan't to write your own interpreter :P

If you want to display for user an apostrophe you need to escape it with \'

Moreover, you can echo string also with double quote so:

```
<?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?>
<?php echo '<p>\'Hello World\'</p>'; ?>
<?php echo "<p>Hello World</p>"; ?>
```

will work.

You will find more information about strings [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: This wasn't the issue.  The issue is that text editor is using curly quotes as opposed to the straight quotes.  I figured it out though.  To type an upright quote I had to hold down the ctrl key.

Comment: Why don't you use some normal editor like PDT eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the font to Arial, I just checked and it appears to use the apostrophe instead of the single quote, when I copied and pasted the example it recognized both characters